# What are letters in parentheses (no chords)?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

I have piano sheet music (~100 measures).
At two bars, there's a letter in parentheses added - (a) and (e).
Due to the context, I don't think it's chord symbols.

My first guess was, it's additional notes that should/could(?) be played here (similar to the first example in [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40573/what-are-parenthesis-used-for-in-notation)). I wouldn't know, whether to play the note in addition or in exchange to one of the other notes, though.

On the other hand, I would have expected the notehead in parentheses, not its name.
Hence, I wonder if these letters denote something else. Does anyone know?

[image: excerpt]

Background info: This is from a piano arrangement of "[I'd do anything for love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27d_Do_Anything_for_Love_(But_I_Won%27t_Do_That))" (M/T Jim Steinmann).
It seems, the score is from the magazine "Keyboards", probably the [issue 1/1994](https://www.keyboards.de/heftarchiv/1994-01/). The score itself is not available *via* the linked online archive. The arranger Wolfgang Wierzyk has published several score collections and own compositions - but I couldn't find this song so far.

Comment: Typically, these would be footnote references. What is the piece, and what edition (i.e., where did the sheets come from)?

Comment: @Aaron I see. It's a pop-song arrangement that was given to me as a copy for rehearsal. (probably a copy of a copy). If it's really footnotes, the explanation is given at another page (of the songbook, I assume). I'll have to ask if the original is available. Untill then I'll just ignore it :)  Anyway, I  guess you can rewrite your comment as an answer.

Comment: Is asking about the original something you imagine doing in the near future? If yes, I'll hold off until the new information is available.

Comment: @Aaron I partly figured it out already: it's from the early 1990s, a magazine about keyboards and electronic music printed a transkription of a pop-song in each issue. I guess it might take a while to find a library that kept those old issues.

Comment: The more information you can include in your post (name of piece, title of magazine), the more likely someone can give a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Aaron I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was printed in a hobbyist magazine, I think we can be fairly certain they are references to the accompanying text.   It's certainly not any sort of optional notation.